# Xamarin iOS UIScrollView With Next/Previous Page Preview: Zoom Not Working as Expected

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a paged UIScrollView that's populated with a collection of UIImageViews. The scroll view shows a preview of the previous and next page.

My goal is to make each page of the scroll view zoomable. Here's a gif of the problem I'm experiencing, where the other pages appear to change their coordinates as the image is zoomed:

[image]

I believe the zoom itself is causing the ContentSize of the scroll view to change drastically, which throws everything else out of sorts.

**StoryBoard Hierarchy**

[Controller]

---- [UIView]

-------- [UIScrollView], Custom Class `CapturedResultScrollView`

My `UIScrollView` has the following constraints to its parent UIView:

[image]

**Code**

Here's the `CapturedResultScrollView` implementation, as well as the delegate:

```
public class CaptureResultScrollViewDelegate : UIScrollViewDelegate {
    public CaptureResultScrollViewDelegate(IHandlePaging pageHandler) {
        this.pageHandler = pageHandler ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pageHandler));
    }

    private readonly IHandlePaging pageHandler;

    public override UIView ViewForZoomingInScrollView(UIScrollView scrollView) {
        var pageIndex = (int)Math.Round(scrollView.ContentOffset.X / scrollView.Frame.Size.Width);
        return pageHandler.Pages[pageIndex];
    }
}

public interface IHandlePaging {
    UIImageView[] Pages { get; set; }
}

public partial class CaptureResultScrollView : UIScrollView, IHandlePaging {
    public CaptureResultScrollView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) {
        MinimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
        MaximumZoomScale = 3.0f;
        ZoomScale = 1.0f;
        PagingEnabled = true;
        ClipsToBounds = false;
        ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
        ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
        Delegate = new CaptureResultScrollViewDelegate(this);
    }

    public UIImageView[] Pages { get; set; }

    public void Setup(IList<CapturedResultModel> capturedResults) {
        // setup called from another controller during segue
        Pages = new UIImageView[capturedResults.Count];

        var pageSize = Frame.Size;
        ContentSize = new CGSize(pageSize.Width * Pages.Length, pageSize.Height);

        for (int page = 0; page < capturedResults.Count; page++) {
            var imageView = new UIImageView() {
                // hardcoded value allow for preview of previous/next pages.
                Frame = new CGRect(pageSize.Width * page, 0, pageSize.Width - 30, pageSize.Height),
                ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill,
                Image = UIImage.FromFile(capturedResults[page].ResultImagePath),
                ClipsToBounds = true
            };

            AddSubview(imageView);
            Pages[page] = imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Setup` method of  `CaptureResultScrollView` is called when the containing controller's `ViewWillAppear` event is triggered as follows:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated) {
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    CapturedResultScrollView.Setup(CapturedResults);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

I think your problem is that you set your `imageView` for the method `ViewForZoomingInScrollView`, when you zoom the `imageview` you selected, only that `imageView` will zoom and the other imageViews will keep their positions in their superView(here is `ScrollerView`),so the other pages appear to change their coordinates as the image is zoomed.

```
  public override UIView ViewForZoomingInScrollView(UIScrollView scrollView) {
        var pageIndex = (int)Math.Round(scrollView.ContentOffset.X / scrollView.Frame.Size.Width);
        return pageHandler.Pages[pageIndex];
    }
```

**Solution:**

My advice is that you can add a view who has the same frame with the ScrollView as your imageView's superview. And set this view to the method `ViewForZoomingInScrollView`'s return value instead of the imageView,so when you zoom this view, imageViews will zoom correctly.

Here is my code:

1.Add a backView in you `IHandlePaging` interface

```
 public interface IHandlePaging
    {
        UIImageView[] Pages { get; set; }

        UIView backView { get; set; }

    }
```

2.Add this `backView` to the ScrovllView and Add the ImageViews to this backView

```
 public void Setup(IList<CapturedResultModel> capturedResults)
        {

            Pages = new UIImageView[capturedResults.Count];
            var pageSize = Frame.Size;
            ContentSize = new CGSize(pageSize.Width * Pages.Length, pageSize.Height);

            backView = new UIView()
            {
               //set the backView's size same as scrollview's contentSize
                Frame = new CGRect(15,40,pageSize.Width * capturedResults.Count, pageSize.Height),                
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue,
                ClipsToBounds = true
            };

            Add(backView);

            for (int page = 0; page < capturedResults.Count; page++)
            {       

                var imageView = new UIImageView()
                {

                    Frame = new CGRect( pageSize.Width * page, 0,pageSize.Width - 30, pageSize.Height),                    
                    Image = UIImage.FromBundle(capturedResults[page].ResultImagePath),
                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue,
                    ClipsToBounds = true
                };

                backView.AddSubview(imageView);
                Pages[page] = imageView;

            }
        }
```

3.Set the `backView` to the method `ViewForZoomingInScrollView`'s return Value

```
  public class CaptureResultScrollViewDelegate : UIScrollViewDelegate
    {
        public CaptureResultScrollViewDelegate(IHandlePaging pageHandler)
        {
            this.pageHandler = pageHandler ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pageHandler));
        }

        private readonly IHandlePaging pageHandler;

        public override UIView ViewForZoomingInScrollView(UIScrollView scrollView)
        {
            var pageIndex = (int)Math.Round(scrollView.ContentOffset.X / scrollView.Frame.Size.Width);
            return pageHandler.backView;

        }
    }
```

4.At last, call the `Setup` method of `CaptureResultScrollView`

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            IList<CapturedResultModel> CapturedResults = new List< CapturedResultModel >{ new CapturedResultModel { ResultImagePath = "Images1" },
                                                                                          new CapturedResultModel { ResultImagePath = "Images2"},
                                                                                          new CapturedResultModel { ResultImagePath = "Images1" }
                                                                                          };

            CaptureResultScrollView CapturedResultScrollView = new CaptureResultScrollView();
            CapturedResultScrollView.Frame = new CGRect(15, 40, View.Frame.Size.Width - 30, View.Frame.Size.Height-80);
            CapturedResultScrollView.Setup(CapturedResults);
            Add(CapturedResultScrollView);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! That's absolutely what's going on, and makes complete sense. Of course the others images attempt to keep their coordinates. I've worked in what you suggested and it works perfectly. Thank you, Jack Hua, and welcome to Stack Overflow!